# PHP float compare

Tags: php

I would like to know why returns false the `var_dump` in the last case

```
var_dump(66*0.1);
var_dump(6.6);
var_dump((66*0.1) == 6.6);
```

The output:

```
float(6.6)
float(6.6)
bool(false)
```

if I use `round` it works fine:

```
var_dump(round(66*0.1, 1) == 6.6);
bool(true)
```

Can someone describe me what is wrong with the php floats?

Comment: Read this (no, really, read it, you will be a better programmer if you do): http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is inherited from `C` language.

There will be a small difference while comparing floating values,

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), ans [this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/5836/What-Every-Computer-Scientist-Should-Know-About-Floating-Point-Arithmetic)

try this,

```
if (abs((6.6 - 6.6)/ 6.6) < 0.00001) {
    echo '<br />Both are equal ';
}
else{
    echo '<br />Both are not equal ';
}
```

Comment: @MrRP Got the idea now??

Answer (score 0):

Probably because PHP like most programming languages and CPUs cannot represent floating point numbers exactly. Refer to this article for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: Almost. The binary system cannot represent *some* floating point numbers exactly.

Comment: That's true. It's because the actual number is represented as a value between 0 and 1 (ignoring negative numbers for now) which is multiplied by the exponent of the FP number. The actual number, as you say, cannot be exactly represented by a binary number unless it's a power of 2 or zero.